# if all new options are selected as modules, can I skip updating /boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, configure

In order to install libvirt on gentoo, I switched on the following config options as module:

```
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK_T
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES
CONFIG_IP6_NF_FILTER
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MANGLE
CONFIG_IP6_NF_NAT
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_NAT
CONFIG_NET_ACT_POLICE
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ACT
CONFIG_NET_CLS_FW
CONFIG_NET_CLS_U32
CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS
CONFIG_NET_SCH_SFQ
```

Can I skip `make install` and only do `make modules_install` since all of them are built as modules?

Comment: Do you know that none of the CONFIG_xx definitions that were changed are used anywhere else in the kernel?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I built many modules that are used in iptables (which are used by `firejail`) and they might get affected.